# Why is this true about eigen values?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$\lambda$ is an eigen value of $T$ iff $T-\lambda I$ is invertible.

Edit: The statement is wrong, and $\lambda$ is an eigen value of $T$ iff $T-\lambda I$ is NOT invertible.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the definition of eigenvalue? What conditions do you know for matrices which are not infertile?

Comment: I feel the statement is wrong and it should be the case that T has an eigen value $\lambda$ iff $T-\lambda I$ is not invertible. Because if $T-\lambda I$ is invertible, then $det T-\lambda I$ is necessarily non-zero. But we find eigen values precisely by equating the characteristic polynomial $det T-\lambda I$ to zero.

Comment: You are correct, and I misread the question. The question is false, $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue if and only if $T-\lambda I$ is **not** invertible.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes thank you. I was just horribly confused while reading my lecture notes!